# Python: Select specific columns in json.dumps()

Tags: python, json

I need to select specific columns from a python dictionary using json.dumps().

Eg.

```
dict={"Greet":"Hello","Bike":"Yamaha","Car":"Jaguar"}
r=json.dumps(Only want "Bike":Yamaha","Car":"Jaguar")
```

Note: Cannot store the same into other dictionary and use it. As I want to use First K,V pair as well in my code.

Comment: "Cannot store the same into other dictionary and use it." Why not? "As I want to use First K,V pair as well in my code." Why should that cause a problem? If you make a **different** dictionary, then you **still have the first one**, and can use it just the same.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new dictionary and dump that.

```
d={"Greet":"Hello","Bike":Yamaha","Car":"Jaguar"}
r = json.dumps({"Bike": d["Bike"], "Car": d["Car"]})
```

If you have a list of all the keys you want to keep, you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
d={"Greet":"Hello","Bike":Yamaha","Car":"Jaguar"}
keep = ['Bike', 'Car']
r = json.dumps({key, d[key] for key in keep})
```

If you have a list of the keys you want to omit, you can also use a dictionary comprehension

```
d={"Greet":"Hello","Bike":Yamaha","Car":"Jaguar"}
skip = ['Greet']
r = json.dumps({key, val for key, val in d.items() if key not in skip})
```

BTW, don't use `dict` as a variable name, it's already the name of a built-in function/class.

Answer (score 0):

```
final = list(mydict.items())[1:] #extra key:value tuple list slice of the portion you need
r=json.dumps(dict(final)) #cast to dictionary and dump
```

> Output

```
{"Bike": "Yamaha", "Car": "Jaguar"}
```